# how can I evaluate the following nested quotes echo statement?

Tags: php, html

My problem is that I want **$id** to be evaluated and passed. I attempted to use escape quotes and failed. How can I do it properly?? if I put "" or '' I always get $id to be passed as a string $id

```
echo '<form name="aform" action=go.php?id=$id"  method="POST">'.
```

'';

Comment: use string concatenation.

Comment: Absolute PHP syntax basics: In double quotes variables are parsed – in single quotes they are not. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 0):

Properly concatenate it to the string

```
echo '<form name="aform" action=go.php?id='.$id.'"  method="POST">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use curly braces as a quicker form of concatenation assuming you used double quotes instead of single:

```
echo "<form name='aform' action='go.php?id={$id}'  method='POST'>";
```

OR if you want double quotes to remain in your html you can escape them

```
echo "<form name=\"aform\" action=\"go.php?id={$id}\" method=\"POST\">";
```

Give this page a read:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php